# SharePoint search result link doesn't work

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

Hi I have this SharePoint 2010 Search Server running, the search results are appearing fine in the results page, but when I click on the link nothing happens. It does not go to the search result link nor does it opens the page in a new tab in the search link. 
There seems to be no response regardless how many links [result links] you click after search result links are populated.
Any help?

Comment: Are you using the OOB Master Page or is it customized? Have you tried different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. When you hover the search result, it will display the link of the search result as the picture below.

   [image]
2. Add the site into trusted site in IE.
3. Reset IE settings. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.
4. Create a new page and add search box web part and search results web part to check if the same issue will occur.